# Python: Combining two lists and removing duplicates in a functional programming way

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function that would combine two lists while removing duplicate items, but in a pure functional way.
For example:

```
a = [1,2,2]
b = [1,3,3,4,5,0]
union(a,b) --> [1,2,3,4,5,0]
```

The imperative form of the code would be:

```
def union(a,b):
    c = []
    for i in a + b:
        if i not in c:
            c.append(i)
    return c
```

I've tried several approaches, but couldn't find a way to do that without using a loop to go over the items - what am I missing?

Answer (score 16):

```
list(set(a + b))
```

This combines two lists `a` and `b` and using `set` takes only unique vales and then we can make it back to `list`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the order you can use `collections.OrderedDict`, otherwise just use `set`. These data structures use hash values of their items for preserving them, thus they don't keep the duplicates.

```
In [11]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [12]: list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a+b))
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `sets`?

```
>>> a = [1,2,2]
>>> b = [1,3,3,4,5,0]
>>> list(set(a).union(set(b)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: The `set` doesn't preserve  the order.

Comment: OP never asked that he want to preserve the order?

Comment: Unfortunately I **am** looking to preserve the order, so this doesn't solve my problem, although I do appreciate the simplicity of the solution

Comment: @DanielR: Then You **must** mention that in your question. We can't guess what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the two lists:

```
a = [1,2,2]
b = [1,3,3,4,5,0]
```

Using sets:

```
union = set(a) | set(b)
# -> set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Using comprehension list:

```
union = a + [x for x in b if x not in a]
# -> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 0]
```

Using loop, without duplicates, preserving order:

```
union = []
for x in a + b:
    if x not in union:
        union.append(x)
# -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> list(set(x).union(set(y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind importing libraries use `toolz` for that (http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which is generally a valuable and widely used helper for functional programming with Python. It has a function named `unique` (http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique), that does exactly what you want.

```
from toolz.itertoolz import unique
a = [1,2,2,3,0]
b = [1,3,3,4,5,0]
c = a + b # could do that with itertools.chain() in a more functional way
return list(unique(c))
# -> [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]
```